# .animate step TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am building some svg animations using raphael.js. I am trying to build a pie chart. I call a function within a step option through the .animate() method.

The error I get: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 
Which is this line: pie_fill.attrs({'path': arc(1, 2, 3, 4)});

It doesn't even understand arc() as a function at all within the step option. However I have no idea why, please help.

```
var R = Raphael("paper");
pie_fill = R.path(("M 150 77 L77 77 Z")).attr({'fill':'#009bca', 'stroke':'#1c1c1c', 'stroke-opacity':'1', 'stroke-width':'1'});

var pie = new Raphael($('#paper'), 300, 154);
    $('#paper').animate({
            'margin': '0'
        }, {
            'duration': 1500,
            step: function( now, fx ) {
                pie_fill.attr({'path': arc(1, 2, 3, 4)});
            }
        });

    arc =function(center, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
        console.log('ran')
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arc is defined after it is called.

If you write `function arc(...)` instead of `arc = function(...)` it should work.